# eval is not recognised on Windows

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I am beginner and I'm trying to connect my GitHub profile with my local machine.

I'm following the steps but my git `cmd` does not recognise `eval`.
I have generated a key and am trying to add an SSH key to the `ssh-agent`.

This is the message I get:

> 'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

The command I run is:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Comment: Show th exact command you're running.

Comment: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running the command in the wrong console.

Open Powershell<sup>1</sup>, Git Bash console or WSL bash - depending on how you installed Git - because this is just Command Prompt (cmd.exe) which doesn't support even the syntax you're trying (Bash).

Or alternatively, ensure `ssh-agent`'s folder is in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Then you'll be able to call it even from a different console, that is, a part of the `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` command.

What that part does is nevertheless incompatible with the Command Prompt console:

```
     -s      Generate Bourne shell commands on stdout.  This is the default if
             SHELL does not look like it's a csh style of shell.
```

and outputs something like this:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-jR0WcW41z0yX/agent.1918430; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=1918431; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 1918431;
```

which might be worked around by using [Command Prompt's `SET` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) like this:

```
set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=c:\some\path\agent.1918430
set SSH_AGENT_PID=<the number you got>
```

and then run the commands following that `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` instruction.

---

<sup>1</sup> PowerShell instance that comes up when opened from the original GitHub toolkit (containing also Git Bash), which preloads some aliases or other functionality. `eval` itself might not be present in the clean instance of PowerShell. When not available, use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://superuser.com/a/1493779/571014).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so grateful that you helped me.

Comment: Welcome. Just in the future provide links to the page(s) you are following and add more description or separate the text so it's more readable. Then the question shouldn't get a lot of downvotes, or any at all.

Comment: Looks like eval does not run on Powershell 7.

-----
PS C:\> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058
eval: The term 'eval' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.